# When streaming JSON to end users, should each buffer be standalone JSON?

Tags: api, web-api

If you were streaming JSON to the end user, and every "buffer" of response was in the format of, for instance...

`{ "something": "here", "other": 1}`

You'd be in a spot where the entire stream together would look like this...

`{ "something": "here", "other": 1}{ "something": "else", "other": 2}`

So the entire response reconstructed isn't actually valid JSON. What do people typically do in this instance?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I'm over-simplifying it, but couldn't you simply return a JSON list?

Comment: @BenCottrell exactly, but unfortunately that isn't a native feature. I'd have to construct that logic, which is undoubtedly complex. I guess the alternative is that I'd expect the consumer to realize the streaming nature of the response and reconstruct as they see fit (as an array, or one by one, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

JSON is not really a streamable format, but you can wrap JSON documents into another format that is. Quite often, this is just one JSON document per line (c.f. http://jsonlines.org/). This is super easy to use but puts some restrictions on JSON generation, notably that each document must not contain any literal newlines.

Your solution where documents are directly adjacent is technically fine because JSON documents always consist of a top-level object or array, but this has some difficulties in practice: You either need a parser that can return the position of any trailing “junk” that is not part of the first document, or you need a lexer to split the stream at the correct locations. Jsonlines avoids this by introducing an explicit, easy to find separator (the line break).

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending multiple blobs of well-formed JSON, you'd need to put a separator between them so the receiver knows where one blob ends and the next begins.  That's obviously not going to meet the standard, because [ECMA 404](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm) doesn't provide for anything like that.  Fortunately, the IETF stepped in and adopted [RFC 7464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7464) as one way to handle it.  It defines a stream as a group of records delimited at the start by a record separator character (ASCII `RS` or `0x1e`) and at the end by a line feed (ASCII `LF` or `0x0a`).

How you split it up is up to you you, but I'd suggest putting enough data in each blob so the receiving program can verify that it's getting everything and knows where the data ends:

```
<RS>
{ "id": 123, "giant-array": null, ... }
<LF>
<RS>
{ "id": 123, "part": 1, "giant-array": [ 1, 2, 3, ... ] }
<LF>
<RS>
{ "id": 123, "part": 2, "giant-array": [ 101, 102, 103, ... ] }
<LF>
... etc. ...
<RS>
{ "id": 123, "part": 2, "giant-array": null }
<LF>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsers expect complete and correct JSON documents and refuse to parse anything else. And JSON documents can contain almost arbitrary characters.

Given n valid documents, you can easily create an array of n items. If the receiver needs to split what it receives into documents, then separate the JSON by nul characters (ASCII 0), because no valid JSON document can contain a nul character.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org) (also *JSONL*) is a well-known and documented standard for streaming data as a series of JSON *"records"*:

- A valid JSON object per line, delimited by a *newline*, and ending in EOF.

It is natively supported in environments that support both JSON and streams delimited by newlines, and there are specific libraries that support it in many languages.

In the case you describe, you only need to assert that the steam format is **JSONL**.